# Xmingrc Configuration

Tags: windows, configuration, x11

With this config file

```
silentexit

Styles {
    emacs maximize
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
...
Release: 6.9.0.31
...
D:\programs\Xming\Xming.exe :0 -clipboard -multiwindow 

XdmcpRegisterConnection: newAddress 192.168.2.10
winPrefsLoadPreferences: C:\Documents and Settings\root/Xmingrc
LoadPreferences: syntax error, unexpected STRING line 3
...
```

I've tried many different variations in capitalization, blank lines, command ordering and removing `silentexit` but to no avail. Otherwise, Xming works; loading emacs is not a problem (except that I have to maximize the screen manually).

I'm actually looking for two things:

1. what's wrong with this file
2. a more detailed explanation on configuring Xmingrc files

WRT item 2 for example, the [man](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/xmingrc.php) page for xmingrc gives the following format for styles:

```
STYLES {
    Class|Name Group1 Group2
    ...
}
```

but gives no indication as to what a `Class` is and only infers a `Name` with an example.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Styles keyword was introduced after the latest public domain release (6.9.something).
I had the same problem and didn't realize that I have to donate to get the latest version.